# Using Sphinx with PHP with multiple indexes

Tags: php, search, full-text-search, sphinx

I've asked a few similar questions but probably didn't provide all the info required.

I have setup the latest version of Sphinx - and have created the indexes (although I'm not 100% i've optimised this configuration) (see the pastebin link at the bottom for this config)

Below is the script that connects to the Sphinx API with the string 'teaching' that i'd like to perform a search on - currently I have four indexes (see the config here - http://pastebin.com/DGgheqYm) i'd need to be able to determine which index that each results come from as this will determine which table that i'll need to perform the query on

eg..

```
// {$table}/{$pk} would vary depending on which index we are using (eg if articles index - then it would use the table called 'articles'
$IDs = implode(",",array_keys($result["matches"]));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$pk} IN ($IDs) ORDER BY FIELD(`id`,$IDs)"
```

With the array of IDs it returns can anyone suggest the best way to :-

- Determine which index a result is coming from to determine the query
- And..if I am doing this the 'right way' - bit of a noob with Spinx :)

  ```
  <?php
  include('api/sphinxapi.php');
  $cl = new SphinxClient();
  $cl->SetServer( "localhost", 9312 );
  $cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_ANY  );
  $result = $cl->Query( "teaching" );

  if ( $result === false ) {
  echo "Query failed: " . $cl->GetLastError() . ".\n";
  }
  else {
  if ( $cl->GetLastWarning() ) {
    echo "WARNING: " . $cl->GetLastWarning() . "
  ";
  }

  if ( ! empty($result["matches"]) ) {
    foreach ( $result["matches"] as $doc => $docinfo ) {
          echo "$doc\n";
    }

    print_r( $result );
   }
   }

   exit;
   ?>
  ```

http://pastebin.com/rDYa3MUj
http://pastebin.com/DGgheqYm

UPDATE : Still having problems here is the output from Sphinx API - I cannot understand why my attributes that i've added using the help from Barry's post doesn't seem to appear
http://pastebin.com/jzBexCBq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each index sets an 'constant' attribute....

```
source articles
...
sql_query = SELECT ID, 1 AS table_id, Title, Description FROM articles
sql_attr_uint = table_id
...

source publications
...
sql_query = SELECT Title_ID, 2 AS table_id, Title, PageTitle, PageContent, Description FROM publications
sql_attr_uint = table_id
...

//etc
```

Then

```
foreach ( $result["matches"] as $doc => $docinfo ) {
    switch($docinfo['attrs']['table_id']) {
        case 1: echo "Article:$doc\n"; break;
        case 2: echo "Publication:$doc\n"; break;
        case 3: echo "Library Content:$doc\n"; break;
        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the sql_query be exactly as you've shown


eg... SELECT ID, 1 AS Table, Title, Description FROM articles
I've done as your post and when I run indexer --all I get the following error:

`ERROR: index articles: sql_query: You have an error in your syntax.....use near 'Table, Title, Description FROM articles`

There is no column called Table in the articles - any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Ah of course Table, is a reserved word in mysql! It doesn't matter what the attribute is called, it just needs to be the same name in every index, have edited the answer to change to use table_id instead.

Comment: +1 Upvoted because Barry is Awesome. After tearing out most of my hair, I stumbled on a PHP script on his website and it saved my job two days ago! Off-topic, yes I know ^_^

Comment: Barry is pretty awesome!